# getting OnLoad HTML/DOM for an HTML page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, http, dom

I am trying to get the HTML (ie what you see initially when the page completes loading) for some web-page URI. Stripping out all error checking and assuming static HTML, it's a single line of code:

```
function GetDisplayedHTML($uri) {
   return file_get_contents($uri);
}
```

This works fine for static HTML, and is easy to extend by simple parsing, if the page has static file dependencies/references. So tags like `<script src="XXX">, <a href="XXX">, <img src="XXX">, and CSS`, can also be detected and the dependencies returned in an array, if they matter.

But what about web pages where the HTML is dynamically created using events/AJAX? For example suppose the HTML for the web page is just a brief AJAX-based or OnLoad script that builds the visible web page? Then parsing alone won't work.

I guess what I need is a way from within PHP, to open and render the http response (ie the HTML we get at first) via some javascript engine or browser, and once it 'stabilises', capture the HTML (or static DOM?) that's now present, which will be what the user's actually seeing.

Since such a webpage could continually change itself, I'd have to define "stable" (OnLoad or after X seconds?). I also don't need to capture any timer or async event states (ie "things set in motion that might cause web page updates at some future time"). I only need enough of the DOM to represent the static appearance the user could see, at that time.

What would I need to do, to achieve this programmatically in PHP?

Comment: There are pre-rendering services which will proxy in the page, process the javascript, and provide the rendered html. Many developers who use javascript-intensive apps use these services to output the rendered content to Google and other search engines. It sounds like you need to take an approach like that. Something like this maybe: https://github.com/prerender/prerender

Comment: I don't want to rely on a third party online service. But I see that prerender is a shim for [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), which runs on many platforms, and has examples for use.  Im guessing that can be run from within PHP code and might solve the problem? Do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render page with JS you need to use some browser. PhantomJS was created for tasks like this. Here is simple script to run with Phantom:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length === 1) {
    console.log('First argument must be page URL!');
} else {
    page.open(args[1], function (status) {
        window.setTimeout(function () { //Wait for scripts to run
            var content = page.content;
            console.log(content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

It returns resulting HTML to console output.
You can run it from console like this:

```
./phantomjs.exe render.js http://yandex.ru
```

Or you can use PHP to run it:

```
<?php
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$html = shell_exec($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phantomjs.exe render.js http://phantomjs.org/');

echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

My PHP code assumes that PhantomJS executable is in the same directory as PHP script.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I'd be running it from PHP so the example helps. One thing that would help - assuming that the page content should be dumped and PhantomJS exits either  X seconds after start or X seconds after the OnLoad event runs (in case the page load and event code means there isn't clarity when it should be dumped or is a slow loader, or any other reason I have to decide a time limit), I can see that I can feed that into PhantomJS but it takes more knowhow than I have - any help with that bit?

Comment: I believe page.open callback is ran after onLoad event. You can wait for page JS to be ran by setting some timeout. I have updated my answer with timeout for 500 milliseconds.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! So this callback includes allowing for page load timing "plus a bit", which is almost perfect.  I've marked it as an answer. One question if it's easy - if the page tries to access something from a URL/IP that's blocked at the gateway (a few of the worst tracker scripts are blocked as they slow machines down), then onLoad won't trigger until web timeout (~ 30 sec), making it slow. Can anything be done so that regardless of page loading, it also won't wait more than say 5000ms from starting?

Comment: You can try page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000; Here is documentation for this option http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html. I have not tried it yet.